# R_PPC_REL24 relocation out of range

Tags: python, c, gcc, swig, powerpc

I am working on an embedded powerpc (e500v2) platform. I am cross compiling compiling with gcc 4.6.3 and eglibc 2.13. There is a swig library that is compiled and loaded on the target. When its loaded in python I am getting this error in a traceback:

```
ImportError: /opt/load/lib/libISSDcn.so: R_PPC_REL24 relocation at 0x0ddc99c0 for symbol `longjmp' out of range
```

I have struggles with this library before, I am migrating from python 2.5 on our target to 2.7. When I initially attempted to compile this library I was getting either relocation errors or operand out of range errors at compile time depending on which flags I used. I switched to gcc 4.6.3 and now it builds, but I am getting this error when its loaded.

I am trying to understand the error, but so far I am in the dark on exactly what it means and how to fix it. I get that a symbol can't be found for some reason, but I don't understand why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `R_PPC_REL24` relocation is used for 24 bit relative offsets. Relocations of this type should not appear in dynamic relocation tables (these are meant for references inside a loadable object, not between them, as libraries can be loaded to addresses more than 16 MiB apart).

By default, the compiler generates these relocs whenever possible, as this is significantly smaller and faster code than using full 32 bit addresses, however for dynamic linking, full addresses need to be used for externally visible symbols and PIC/GOT entries generated.

Check that the `-fPIC` flag was used for building the library, and that the linker was also notified that it is building a shared object (typically, via `-shared` or `-Bshared`).

Comment: Okay, thanks I have seen that suggested elsewhere. I was told this library was compiled with fPIC, but its certainly possible it was not. Is there anyway to tell after the fact if a library is or is not PIC?

Comment: Or another question I can ask is, if I do a readelf -r should I expect to see R_PPC_REL24 in a shared object? I see a lot of them. Or does this list include non external symbols?

Comment: A PIC library should not have dynamic relocations applied to anything but the PIC and GOT areas, and all of these relocations should be able to cover the entire address space.

Comment: `readelf` without the `-D` option shows the information for static linking -- after the final link pass, these relocations have already been applied, except for those pointing to missing symbols (which have been converted to dynamic relocs).

Comment: Alright, it was difficult to track down because my project has a lot of code and third party modules, but there was code compiled without -fPIC. Now its working, thanks! For anyone else that runs into it, just run 'readelf -D -r | grep R_PPC_REL24'. If it finds any R_PPC_REL24 relocs, there is some objects being compiled without -fPIC.